# Build htdig on ubuntu machine

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

On my Ubuntu machine, htdig (www.htdig.org) is installed. e.g. "which htdig" gives me, /usr/bin/htdig

I want to install htdig under /var/www/my_web_site
i.e. /var/www/my_web_site/htdig

Extra info:

- gcc version 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6)
- GNU Make 4.0

For htdig-3.1.6:

When I run "./configure", I got:

> configure: error: To compile ht://Dig, you will need a C++ library.
>   Try installing libstdc++

"Run /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++"

I have:

- libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
- libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

---

I also tried out **htdig-3.2.0b6**:

I run "./configure", and it seems fine. I got something like *"Now you must run 'make' followed by 'make install'"*

When I run "make", I got quite a few errors like:

```
.....
Making all in htsearch
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/www/test/testme/sounddesign/htdig-3.2.0b6/htsearch'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../include -DDEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE=\"/opt/www/conf/htdig.conf\" -I../include -I../htlib -I../htnet -I../htcommon -I../htword -I../db -I../db -DCONFIG_DIR=\"/opt/www/conf\" -I../htfuzzy     -g -O2 -Wall -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -c -o Display.o `test -f 'Display.cc' || echo './'`Display.cc
In file included from Display.cc:30:0:
Collection.h:39:10: error: extra qualification ‘Collection::’ on member ‘Open’ [-fpermissive]
     void Collection::Open();
....
....
....
Display.cc:830:32: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     if (input->exists("endyear"))
                                ^
```

Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining that the class prefix `Collection::` in Collection.h is both unnecessary, and now, illegal.

Simply change the htsearch/Collection.h header to this:

```
class Collection : public Object
{
public:
    //
    // Construction/Destruction
    //
    Collection(const char *name, const char *wordFile,
               const char *indexFile, const char *docFile,
               const char *docExcerpt);
    ~Collection();

    // COMMENT OUT OR REMOVE THESE TWO LINES:
    //    void Collection::Open();
    //    void Collection::Close();
    // ADD THESE TWO:
    void Open();
    void Close();
```

(comment out/remove old lines declaring Open/Close and add the last two lines above)

After doing this, htdig 3.2 b 6 compiled successfully for me. The warnings are just that: warnings. They won't prevent successful compilation. This is now a very old codebase, and some of the C++ is invariably not compliant with current compiler standards.